# linked list deletion algorithm

Tags: list, linked-list

this program is used to delete a node from a linked list.It works fine but the thing is that it prints 0 instead of NOT printing the value of the deleted node.
For ex. If my list is 1-->2-->3-->-999.And I want to delete say 2. Then the final list is printed as 1-->0-->-->3-->-999.Why the 0???

```
enter code here
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>
struct list {
        int number;
        struct list *next;
        };
typedef struct list node;
void create(node *);
void print(node *);
node *delete(node *,int);
main() {
int key;
node *head;
head = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
create(head);
printf("Your list as you entered is....................\n");
print(head);
printf("Which element do you want to delete?\n ");
scanf("%d",&key);
head = delete(head,key);
printf("The new list is ..............................\n ");
print(head);
return 0;
}
void create(node *list) {
        printf("Enter a number,-999 to stop data entrying\n");
        scanf("%d",&list->number);
        if(list->number == -999) {
                list->next = NULL;
        }
        else {
                list->next = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
                create(list->next);
        }
}
void print(node *list) {
        if(list->number != -999) {
                printf("%d-->",list->number);
                print(list->next); }
        else {
                printf("%d",list->number);
        }
}
node *delete(node *list,int key) {
        node *prev_ptr = NULL;
        node *curr_ptr;
        for(curr_ptr=list;curr_ptr!=NULL;prev_ptr=curr_ptr,curr_ptr=curr_ptr->next) {
        if(curr_ptr->number == key) {
                break;
        }
        }
        if(prev_ptr == NULL) {
                list = curr_ptr->next;
        }
        else {
                prev_ptr = curr_ptr->next;
                }
        free(curr_ptr);
        return(list);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in rearranging the pointers in delete routine.
Instead of

```
...
else {
    prev_ptr = curr_ptr->next;
}
...
```

You should have

```
...    
else {
    prev_ptr->next = curr_ptr->next;
}
...
```

The 0 is being shown because you free curr_ptr (thus it points to nowhere). But the real issue is you shouldn't have it in the list.